# ColdBox 4.1.0 - Error creating eviction policy: LRU

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I am using CF11 update 5. I downloaded ColdBox 4.1.0 and as the documentation says, I copied the downloaded folder to web-root and renamed the folder to coldbox. When I try to run any of the sample applications, I get the following error.

[image]

I don't know what the problem is. I searched the internet and found one related stuff-
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/coldbox/fwmYOa4sLpY/YxmUmhroqaoJ

But that doesn't seem to solve the issue.
Do anyone know how to sort it out?

Comment: Please enable ColdFusion's robust exception messages or enable a Logbox logger to see the real error which is contained in the "detail".

Comment: @BradWood Robust exception messages are already enabled.

Comment: Did you crop your screenshot then, because I don't see the rest of the error detail.  All I see are the message, type, and tag stack.

Comment: I tried the ColdBox sample apps on ColdFusion 11 Update 5 and ColdBox 4.1 and I do not encounter this error.  You'll need to get to the bottom of the actual error message and share some additional details about your setup.  It's quite possibly related to mappings, or folder paths.

Comment: @BradWood I have added the full error message.

Comment: Thanks, that error indicates that this fileExist() returned false: https://github.com/ColdBox/coldbox-platform/blob/master/system/cache/providers/CacheBoxProvider.cfc#L149  meaning the file /coldbox/system/cache/policies/LRU.cfc wasn't found.  I'd start by confirming that file exists and then put in some dump/abort debugging code in that file to see what's going on.  Sounds like the /coldbox mapping isn't resolving correctly.